# Error in Firebase storage while trying to get a reference (using Angulafire2)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I have an app which uses Angularfire2 (2.0.0-beta.8) and Firebase (firebase@3.7.0). The app can read from and write to the database, just to say that access to Firebase DB works.

The configuration of Firebase (via Angularfire2) is as follows

**firebase.config.ts**

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '................',
    authDomain: 'myapp-xy123.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://myapp-xy123.firebaseio.com',
    storageBucket: '',
    messagingSenderId: '123......678'
};


export const authConfig = {
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Password
};
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .....
  ],
  imports: [
    ......,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, authConfig),
    ......
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now I am trying to use Firebase storage to upload some files. To start the simplest way I have created a method which simple method that uploads 1 file. The method is the following

```
  uploadOneFile(file: File) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const storageRefChild = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg');
    return storageRefChild.put(file);
  }
```

When I run this method (after having being authenticated) I get a `Firebase Storage: Invalid URL 'undefined'` error as can be seen in the following trace

[image: console error trace]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you specify an `appName` in your call to [`initializeApp`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/angularfire2.ts#L116)? If you did, the default app you are accessing via `firebase.storage()` won't have been configured. You would need to call `firebase.app("<your app name>").storage()`, etc.

Comment: I have added the configuration details in the question. There is no appName in the configuration. Thanks for helping

Comment: It looks like you've not specified a storage bucket in the configuration.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#set_up_firebase_storage

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the `storageBucket` by your storage url.

go to your firebase storage and copy the link above `gs://....appspot.com` then fill it inside your `firebaseConfig`

```
storageBucket:"gs://....appspot.com"
```